# Xamarin Form HttpClient Stuck

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpwebrequest, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get response from soundcloud API. Here is my code.

```
public static async Task<string> GetTheGoodStuff()
  {
     var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
     var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists?client_id=17ecae4040e171a5cf25dd0f1ee47f7e&limit=1");
     var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     return responseString;
   }
```

But it's stucks on `var response = await client.GetAsync`. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Without `new NativeMessageHandler()` your code worked for me... BTW instead of blocking `Result` use `await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Have you tried to run this code in PCL project?

Comment: @Eser I think OP is using ModernHttpClient, so need references to that in PCL and native projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did just use your code in a PCL, only thing I changed is the url (to `https`) to satisfy iOS ATS requirements, and called it from an async method. Seems to work fine running on iOS device. I did grab references to `Microsoft.Net.Http` in the PCL, and `ModernHttpClient` in the PCL **and in the platform-specific projects** (via NuGet).

Your code in some PCL view model class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ModernHttpClient;

public class ItemsViewModel
{

...

    public async Task<string> GetPlaylist()
    {
        // Use https to satisfy iOS ATS requirements.
        var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists?client_id=17ecae4040e171a5cf25dd0f1ee47f7e&limit=1");
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString;
    }

...

}
```

Then in a PCL page class that instantiates and uses an instance of the view model:

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Vm = new ItemsViewModel();
        BindingContext = Vm;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var playlist = await Vm.GetPlaylist();
        // Do something cool with the string, maybe some data binding.
    }

    // Public for data binding.
    public ItemsViewModel Vm { get; private set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I fixed it by:

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(ApiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

you can try it.